# Win32 API For Sending Messages Between Computers

Tags: c, winapi, messaging

What is the Win32 API for sending messages between computers? I mean, what used to be achieved by the "net send" command and is now using "msg". I imagine it is some API over NetBIOS?

Comment: I don't think that is a "Win 32 API" but a choice of net work protocol and then using the features (API or 3rd party library) to use that protocol

Comment: Actually, `net send` and `msg` use the [`WTSSendMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383842.aspx) function.

Comment: Thanks, Remy! Why don't you add a response so that I can accept it?

Comment: @RicardoPeres: done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `net send` and `msg` use the [`WTSSendMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383842.aspx) function.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is version-specific, since `net send` has been around a long time, compared to WTS.

Comment: WTS has been around since Windows 2000.

Comment: and `net send` has been [around since WinNT 3.5](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/168893)